# How to listen for "Stop sharing" click in Chrome DesktopCapture API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I'm currently writing a chrome extension which uses [Chrome's DesktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture). I'm struggling to set a callback when someone clicks on "Stop sharing".

[image: Stop sharing Screenshot]

I tried using the `onended` [EventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_API) of the MediaStream, but the MediaStream's `ended` property is still set to `true` after clicking on the button.

The only difference I could find between the stream (before and after clicking the button) is that the `videoTracks.readyState` is set to `ended`.

Edit:
I would also like to notice if the user closes the window they were streaming before.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I solved this issue by assigning an EventHandler on the **videoTrack's** `onended` property:

```
  // somebody clicked on "Stop sharing"
  stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = function () {
    // doWhatYouNeedToDo();
  };
```

As far as my edit goes (noticing a closing window): it also fires the event.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you putting this information here.  I am having an issue with the desktopCapture over RTCPeerConnection.  Would you mind taking a look at [my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26111693/1375316)

Comment: Is there a way I can have my own stop sharing button in application and avoid using  this chrome bar/ tray? If yes, please let me know how can I hide it completely?

Comment: @user2801184 You can have a custom stop sharing button. But I don't think you can avoid having the chrome bar/tray. You could ask/report on webrtc mailing list though.

Comment: @wpp I wrote a custom button and used shareStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop(); I will report it to webrtc mail. Can you please answer this question if its possible?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235155/chrome-webrtc-screen-sharing-minimizing-and-maximizing-screen-shows-black-scree

Comment: @wpp I am using video js. Where do I put these codes.?

Comment: This works in screen share, window share scenarios.  But not in tab share scenarios.

Answer (score 14):

Now we have oninactive, You can use like this

```
stream.oninactive = () => {}
```

Comment: This works in screen share, window share & tab share scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

```
stream.onended = () => { // Click on browser UI stop sharing button
  console.info("Recording has ended");
};
```

Where to get stream? Using adapter.js (making universal Promise based API across browsers):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(..).then((stream) => {..});
```