# RTCPeerConnection media stream working in firefox but not chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

Trying to keep the problem as simple as possible, I am creating a media stream in a chrome extension like so:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen', 'window'], null, function(streamId) {
    var constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
            }
        }
    },
    success = function(stream) {
        pc.addStream(stream);
        pc.createOffer(function(offer) {
            pc.setLocalDescription(offer, function() {
                send('make_offer', name, offer);
            }, printError);
        }, printError);
    };
    getUserMedia(constraints, success, printError);
});
```

For now, my offer is received by a peer visiting a page in a browser.  That looks more or less like this (m is a message object with the offer):

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
pc.onaddstream = function(e) {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
};
pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(m.value), function() {
    pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
        pc.setLocalDescription(answer, function() {
            send('make_answer', m.from, answer);
        }, printError);
    }, printError);
}, printError);
```

I have done this, both with and without ice servers, which look like this when I use them:

```
var iceServers = {
    iceServers: [
        {url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}
    ]
};
```

Right now, the peer receives and displays the stream perfectly in Firefox.  No problem at all.  But it's not working in Chrome.  Here is some selected data from chrome://webrtc-internals:
connection to firefox:

```
"ssrc_3309930214_send-transportId": {
 "startTime": "2014-09-30T01:41:11.525Z",
 "endTime": "2014-09-30T01:41:21.606Z",
 "values": "[\"Channel-video-1\",\"Channel-video-1\",\"Channel-video-1\"]"
},
"ssrc_3309930214_send-packetsLost": {
 "startTime": "2014-09-30T01:41:11.525Z",
 "endTime": "2014-09-30T01:41:21.606Z",
 "values": "[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
},
```

connection to chrome:

```
"ssrc_1684026093_send-transportId": {
 "startTime": "2014-09-30T01:41:57.310Z",
 "endTime": "2014-09-30T01:42:00.313Z",
 "values": "[\"Channel-audio-1\",\"Channel-audio-1\",\"Channel-audio-1\",\"Channel-audio-1\"]"
},
"ssrc_1684026093_send-packetsLost": {
 "startTime": "2014-09-30T01:41:57.310Z",
 "endTime": "2014-09-30T01:42:00.313Z",
 "values": "[-1,-1,-1,-1]"  // what is causing this??
},
```

Those seem important, but I'm not sure exactly of the implications.  I have more data, but I'm not sure exactly what is important.  The main idea, is that data goes out to firefox, but not to chrome, though no exceptions occur that I can see.  The one further suspicious piece of data happens if I load the peer page in Chrome Canary (latest):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

This is a console error, and I don't know where it comes from.  It occurs after the answer is sent from the peer back to the host (chrome extension).

Signaling done over wss://, test peer is hosted at https://
I'm not sure where to go from here.

Update:  Based on answer and comment, I added a handler for onicecandidate:

```
pc.onicecandidate = function(e) {
    console.log('This is the ice candidate.');
    console.log(e);
    if(!e.candidate) return console.warn('no candidate!');
    send('got_ice_candidate', name, e.candidate);
};
```

I also set up an equivalent peer connection from browser to browser using video:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: true
};
getUserMedia(constraints, success, printError);
```

This works fine, both from Firefox to Chrome and vise-versa, so the issue may be chrome-extension-specific...
There is a difference in how ice gathering occurs between the successful case and the extension case:

- Between browsers, there is no ice at all.  There is one event, and e.candidate is `null`.
- From extension to browser, there are lots of `onicecandidate` events.  They are not all in agreement.  So perhaps the chrome extension is confusing the STUN server?  I don't know.

Thanks for your answers, would love any more insight that you have.

Comment: can you add 
pc.onicecandidate = function(e){
send('ice_candidate', e.target)
}

And on the other side on receiving this 'message' do
pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message));

Comment: Are the computers on the same network? If they are, ice servers are not needed. Does your same set up work with regular media from a camera?

Comment: Computers are on the same network.  I will test with camera (can't do this from chrome extension though).  Will also check out the iceCandidate handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please add handling ice candidates on both sides ?

`pc.onicecandidate = function(e){ send('ice_candidate', e.target) }`

And on the other side on receiving this 'message' do

`pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message));`

Chrome sends ice candidates even after offer/answer have been exchanged which firefox does not seem to do.

Comment: I spent hours having only added the handler on the initiator.  Once I added it to the remote peer, it worked immediately.  Thank you.  I will also add that the reason Firefox doesn't have this issue is that it doesn't use ice trickling.  It passes ice candidates between peers in the sdp of the answer.

Comment: Note that Firefox now defaults to all-trickle-ICE per the Working Group (I forget if it's in 32/release or 33/beta right now)

Comment: No matter what FF says, it's behaviour is different than chrome in many different ways. Instead of following the way chrome's implementation works they have their own half baked one which doesn't even work some of the time. For instance, I found out ff does not work when talking to chrome when FF is behind a port restricted NAT!! It, however, works 'fine' when working with direct internet, static nat or IP restricted NAT. We found, from FF logs, that doing pc.addIceCandidate was failing with some weird reason. Therefore, we waited for and added all candidates in sdp and it worked!!