# Chrome WebRTC Screen Sharing: Minimizing and Maximizing screen Shows Black Screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot, webrtc

I've been trying to implement [this](https://github.com/emannion/webrtc-application-screen-share) GitHub code and I'm able to share my screen.

But for Windows 10, *if a previously minimised (and shared) window is maximised again, I "loose the share" and see a black screen.* I know this happens [only on Windows](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309129).

I was wondering if subscribing to open and close window events might work in Javascript? Please let me know your suggestions.
Thanks!