# How to get stream object from kurento utils when using kurento java tutorial samples

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Using kurento tutorials java samples. I Want to handle stream events like onended etc on the webrtcpeer object. Following is my sample code from where i want to fetch the stream object.

```
var options = {
           localVideo: video,
           mediaConstraints: constraints,
           onicecandidate: participant.onIceCandidate.bind(participant)
       };

var peer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendonly(options, function(error) {
           if (error) {
               return console.error(error);
           }
           this.generateOffer(participant.offerToReceiveVideo.bind(participant));
       });
```

I want to handle events in a way similar to as mentions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141080/how-to-listen-for-stop-sharing-click-in-chrome-desktopcapture-api)

How should I proceed? Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to those events two ways

- Passing a `onstreamended` listener in the options bag

  ```
  var options = {
         localVideo: video,
         mediaConstraints: constraints,
         onicecandidate: participant.onIceCandidate.bind(participant),
         onstreamended: myOnStreamEnded,
     };
  ```
- Accessing directly the `RTCPeerConnection` object wrapped inside the `WebRtcPeer`, and binding to events directly.

  ```
  var rtcPeerConnection = peer.peerConnection
  ```

The latter gives you full access to the peer connection object, so you can work as if you would with that object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first options worked for me like a charm.

Comment: The onStreamEnded event has been deprecated and chrome says it will be removed by October. Is there anything else that can be used for the same event?