# Get "Stop Sharing" click event in chrome after sharing my screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, screensharing

I got a solution after searching

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = function () {
   //get stop event
};
```

But I got the error

> stream is not defined  no-undef

How can I get this event?

Comment: can we see where you declare the variable `stream`?

Comment: @Neeko I want to declare but i din't know how can i declare this

Comment: I found the solutions from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141080/how-to-listen-for-stop-sharing-click-in-chrome-desktopcapture-api

Comment: So is this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141080/how-to-listen-for-stop-sharing-click-in-chrome-desktopcapture-api ? Or is your problem you do not have a stream at the time you are inquiring

Comment: I dont' have a stream how can i get this

Comment: I have no idea with the lack of code. Post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
if (stream) {
  stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener("ended", () => {
    stopSharing();
  });
}
}, [stream]);
```