# listen to click events of stop sharing button bottom of chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome

is there a way I can listen to click event of stop sharing button which appears bottom of chrome when sharing the screen using angular
[image: stop sharing button]

the method i need to call on click of stop sharing

```
 handleStopRecording() {
    this.recordOption.isStart = !this.recordOption.isStart;
    this.showWebcam = false;
    if (
      this.requestType === "screenAndCamera" ||
      this.requestType === "audioAndScreen"
    ) {
      this.handleStopRecordingOption().then(() => {
        this.handleUploadBlob();
        // this.subscribeVideoObserver();
      });
    }
    if (this.requestType === "cameraAndAudio") {
      this.handleStopCameraRecording().then(() => {
        this.handleUploadBlob();
        // this.subscribeVideoObserver();
      });
    }
```

handlestopRecordingOption

```
  handleStopRecordingOption = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.recorder.stopRecording(() => {
        RecordRTC.getSeekableBlob(this.recorder.getBlob(), (seekableBlob) => {
          this.videoData.videoLength =
            (new Date().getTime() - this.dateStarted) / 1000;
          var blob = seekableBlob;
          this.render.setAttribute(
            this.downloadLinkRef.nativeElement,
            "href",
            URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          );
          this.videoData.videoName = `${moment().format(
            "MM-DD-YYYY__HH-mm-ss"
          )}_recorderVideo.mkv`;
          this.videoData.videoFile = new File([blob], this.videoData.videoName);
          this.recordOption.isDownloadAvailable = true;
          this.render.setProperty(this.video.nativeElement, "muted", true);
          this.render.setProperty(this.video.nativeElement, "srcObject", null);
          this.render.setProperty(
            this.video.nativeElement,
            "src",
            `${URL.createObjectURL(blob)}#t=${this.videoData.videoLength - 2},${
              this.videoData.videoLength
            }`
          );
          this.screen.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
          this.camera.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141080/how-to-listen-for-stop-sharing-click-in-chrome-desktopcapture-api ?

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have gone through this but i am confused how to use it angular app

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yeah i added, i cannot add whole code

Comment: IF it possible can you share handleStopRecordingOption function body?

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have added function